# Live Template for Delphi that generate a Property with getter / setter and create the private field?

Tags: delphi, live-templates

Searching here and on the internet have not let me to a example of a Live Template for Delphi that generate a Property with getter / setter and also generate the private field and execute the complication. (SHIFT + CTRL + C)

Is this possible?

Comment: If you need a real productivity boost in Delphi, then consider MMX (ModelMaker Code Explorer) http://bit.ly/9r1qaV - it is from a Dutch vendoer and tops all other Delphi refactoring tools. --jeroen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example titled "Read/write property" on the already-mentioned [Delphi Live Templates](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Live_Templates) page can be modified to generate getter/setter methods instead of a private field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<codetemplate   xmlns="http://schemas.borland.com/Delphi/2005/codetemplates"
                version="1.0.0">
    <template name="prop" invoke="manual">
        <description>
            read write property for field
        </description>
        <author>
            twm
        </author>
        <point name="ident">
            <text>Name</text>
            <hint>the name for the property</hint>
        </point>
        <point name="type">
            <text>Integer</text>
            <hint>the type for the property</hint>
        </point>
        <script language="Delphi" onenter="false" onleave="true">
            InvokeClassCompletion;
        </script>
        <code language="Delphi" delimiter="|">
        <![CDATA[property |ident|: |type| read Get|ident| write Set|ident|;
|end|]]>
        </code>
    </template>
</codetemplate>
```

This, however, doesn't generate the private field.

Comment: Thanks TOndrej - Thats nearly the same as I use now, but as you say it don't generate the private field.

Comment: Oops. Totally missed the script tag in your example. Sorry!